# Some Arabic characters are Missing In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arabic

I am Trying to make the game in Unity in Which I Have to Write the Name In Arabic.
I am Using the RTL pro Asset to write the Arabic In Input Field But the Issue is That When I try to Write the Character ي it Converts into the ى. The Dot Below the Character are Missing Is there anyone Who is Faced this issue Before or Guide me?
Help will be appreciated...

I am Expecting to Resolve It For the Build of My game.

Comment: We have had issues with RTL with default TMP (binding for instance). We use this one to fix https://github.com/pnarimani/RTLTMPro

Comment: I know It's A bit late but thanks for Your Response.

Comment: Everts, I am using the RTL Pro but I am facing the Issue mentioned on [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817464/the-arabic-is-not-writing-properly-in-unityusing-the-rtl-pro-package?noredirect=1#comment135424586_76817464) will you look at it if you know the Answer. thanks.